# slider javascript library that handles image and text layer at different speed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for jquery image slider plugin, that slides images and text layer at different speed similar to  http://www.apple.com/imac/

This question is similar to [Using javascript modulus to iterate through text slider with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893765), but I want to know if a javascript library exists before working on it.

Thanks

Comment: the word you're looking for is "parallax"

Answer (score 0):

The rendering on that many objects when converted to jQuery will become choppy. For that effect they are using webkit / mozkit animation

Comment: it's not hard to get reasonable animation with jQuery, but I do agree that native browser animation is smoother than JS animation.